How To get consistent and expected json from Autogen?
I'm using multi-agent autogen, where I have multiple critic agents who review writer agent's report. I need to get critic reviews in a specific JSON format, but I'm not getting a consistent and expected JSON as output. How can I get this?
I tried configuring llm config with the below param, but no use.
response_format = {"type": response_format}

Is there any other way to achieve this?
The output which I'm getting:
case1: {"heading":<heading>,"content":content}
case2: [{"reviewer"::<reviewer>,review:{heading...

Expected output:
    response_format =    """- The ouput must be exactly in the below JSON format:
        [
            {
                "heading":"<heading of the comment_1 >",
                "content":"<content in markdown format of comment_1>"
            },
            {
                "heading":"<heading of the comment_2 >",
                "content": "<content in markdown format of comment_2>"
            },
            {
                "heading":"<heading of the comment_n >",
                "content": "<content in markdown format of comment_n>"
            }
        ]
        """


I'm facing the same issue. Kindly help
